# Executing a SQL query during debugging in SQL Server Management Studio on locked table

Tags: sql-server, debugging

Is it possible to somehow execute a query against a table during debugging of T-SQL statement? It's locked for another connections at the time, so using another windows doesn't help.

I'm trying to debug an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger, something isn't working as expected and I'd like to evaluate another SQL expression to investigate.

I think that I maybe could write a cursor that will loop the table and `print` the information I need, but I'd rather avoid that and use something simpler.

Comment: Did you try using the `WITH NOLOCK` hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT ..
  FROM ..
```

OR

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ SNAPSHOT;
SELECT ..
  FROM ..
```

Have a look at the [Transaction Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) levels here.
The first will allows access to 'dirty' uncommitted data whereas the second will skip uncommitted data.  However **neither** will see data in the `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger, since that hasn't even hit the table.

Comment: it will, as I am writing stuff into the table in the trigger. That did the trick!